# Smooth complex projective manifolds with a $\mathbb C^*$-action with isolated fixed points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

What is minimal $n$, such that there exists a smooth complex projective manifold $M^n$ satisfying the following two conditions:

1) The group of automorphisms of $M^n$ is $\mathbb C^*$.

2) All the fixed point of the $\mathbb C^*$-action are isolated and the set of fixed points is non-empty.

Is it possible to get some sort of classification of such manifolds in low dimensions?

Note that $n>2$...

Comment: "with isolated fixed points" should be interpreted as "such that there exists an isolated fixed point", or "such that all fixed points are isolated"?

Comment: Sorry, I finally figured out all the conditions that I've meant and reformulated the question

Comment: I am probably missing something, but it seems to me that for the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by $t\cdot (X,Y,Z)=(X,tY,t^2Z)$, the fixed points are $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @abx there's an additional requirement that there are no further automorphisms. Otherwise the similar action on $\mathbb{P}^1$ already works.

Comment: You want $n\ge 1$, otherwise the action on the point is an example :)

Comment: @YCor: The point has automorphism group a point, contradicting 1).

Comment: Ah yes, my reformulation "there are no further automorphisms" is not accurate in this case...